# Why are API tokens recommended with PyPI?

Tags: python, authentication, token, pypi

From the help text on PyPI about API tokens ([link](https://pypi.org/help/#apitoken)):

> We strongly recommend you authenticate with an API token where possible.

Why is that? What are the issues with using my login/password if I am the only person working on a Python package?

Comment: Usename/passwords are less secure.

Comment: @James How do you know how long my password is?

Comment: It is not about the password length, it is about password reuse.  If you use the same password on another site and it is compromised, then so is the password for PyPi

Comment: Who says I am not using a password manager with an automatically generated password?

Comment: Nobody, but: I doubt you're doing that with a separate account for each package (unless you only have one); and it's tricky to use 2FA from CI.

Comment: Cool. Good for you.  Most people don't.  Recommending using a token-based authentication that is managed by PyPi is easier than recommending someone install and setup a password manager

Comment: See also: http://pyfound.blogspot.com/2019/07/pypi-now-supports-uploading-via-api.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- If you re-use your password elsewhere (you shouldn't, but people do), then if PyPI is compromised, your other accounts could get compromised.
- Using your username and password gives permissions to all of your projects, but tokens can be limited to a single project.
- You can use multiple tokens across multiple machines, so if one token becomes compromised, you can revoke it without affecting other machines or projects.
- PyPI can guarantee that tokens are high entropy.

Comment: Thanks! Practically speaking, since tokens are only shown once, what's the good practice for where and how to store it (e.g. within the repo itself, in an encrypted file, using password manager, ..)?

Comment: @JonathanH well where are you planning to *use* the token? If it's to publish from CI, for example, you can set it as an env var or maybe store it in the settings file (e.g. https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/encryption-keys/ for Travis, for example).

Comment: @JonathanH This depends upon the rest of your infrastructure, but generally speaking this falls under the topic of "secret management" and you can find the right solution for your stack by searching for that.  Don't commit to version control unless it's encrypted by a key that is not committed to version control.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is my first PyPI package, and I am trying to make it easy to update / distribute it. Comitting an encrypted file sounds like an easy solution, but I will also look into CI!